# PHP Uploader wont rename uploads

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP uploader on my Dedi server, the uploader works as it should, only after it uploads the files it dose not rename them from their temp names..

it comes out something like

```
2b4134a1f559b6da866c9febbc92d709.mp3
```

The uploader file.php

```
    <?php

class file {

    public $id;
    public $fileName;
    public $systemFilename;
    public $fileType;
    public $fileExtension;
    public $systemUrl;
    public $originalUrl;
    public $thumbPath;
    public $thumbUrl;
    public $canHaveThumb;
    public $ts;
    public $size;
    public $authorized;
    public $knownExtensions;
    public $mimeType;
    public $filePath;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setKnownExtensions();
    }

    // Check and save a new file on the disk and the database
    public function uploadNewFile($files) {

        $result = array(); // The variable we will send back when we have finished to check and save the file
        $this->setFileName($files['Filedata']['name']);
        if ($this->authorized) {

            // Build the target path
            $siteUrl = F3::get('siteUrl'); // Set in config.php
            $uploadFolder = F3::get('uploadFolder'); // Set in config.php
            $uploadUrl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $uploadFolder . '/';

            // Get the temporary file
            $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

            // Get a unique system name
            $rand = rand(1, 414342);
            $ts = time();
            $systemName = md5($rand . $ts);

            $this->systemFilename = $systemName . '.' . $this->fileExtension;
            $this->ts = $ts;

            // Clean the path
            $targetFile = str_replace('//', '/', $uploadUrl) . $this->systemFilename;
            // Save the file on the disk
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

            // Save the file in the database
            DB::sql('INSERT INTO hm_files (fileName, systemFilename, fileType, time) VALUES ("' . $this->fileName . '", "' . $this->systemFilename . '", "' . $this->fileType . '", ' . $this->ts . ')');
            $this->id = F3::get('DB->pdo')->lastInsertId();

            // Retrieve the template for the file list
            $result['tableRow'] = $this->getTableRow();

            // We create a thumbnail if it is a simple image
            $this->createThumb();
        }

        $result['file'] = $this;
        return $result;
    }

    public function canHaveThumb() {
        if ($this->fileType == 'image') {

            $this->canHaveThumb = true;
        } else {
            $this->canHaveThumb = false;
        }
        return $this->canHaveThumb;
    }

    public function createThumb() {
        if ($this->canHaveThumb()) {
            $filePath = $this->getFilePath();
            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $thumbPath = site::getThumbsPath();
                $thumb = new image($filePath);
                $thumb->dir($thumbPath);
                $thumb->width(250);
                $thumb->save();
            }
        }
    }

    public function getThumbPath() {
        $thumbFolderPath = site::getThumbsPath();
        $this->thumbPath = $thumbFolderPath . $this->systemFilename;

        if (!file_exists($this->thumbPath)) {
            $this->createThumb();
        }

        return $this->thumbPath;
    }

    public function getThumbUrl() {

        $base = F3::get('BASE');
        $thumbsFolder = F3::get('thumbsFolder');
        $this->thumbUrl = $base . '/' . $thumbsFolder . '/' . $this->systemFilename;

        return $this->thumbUrl;
    }

    // Delete a file
    public function delete() {
        $filePath = $this->getFilePath();
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            unlink($filePath); // Remove the file from the hard drive
        }
        if ($this->canHaveThumb()) {
            $thumbPath = $this->getThumbPath();
            if (file_exists($thumbPath)) {

                unlink($thumbPath); // Remove the thumb from the hard drive
            }
        }
        DB::sql('DELETE FROM hm_files WHERE id = ' . $this->id); // Remove from database
    }

    // Set the filename and the file extension
    public function setFileName($fileName) {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
        $this->fileExtension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($this->fileName, '.'), 1));
        $this->checkExtension();
        $this->getFileType();
    }

    // Check if a file has an authorized extension
    public function checkExtension() {
        $okExtensions = F3::get('okExtensions'); // defined in config.php
        if (in_array($this->fileExtension, $okExtensions)) {
            $this->authorized = true;
        } else {
            $this->authorized = false;
        }
        return $this->authorized;
    }

    // Define the file type (eg: image, video, ...)
    // Not used in this version
    public function getFileType() {
        $ext = $this->fileExtension;
        if (isset($this->knownExtensions[$ext])) {
            $this->fileType = $this->knownExtensions[$ext];
        } else {
            $this->fileType = 'file';
        }
        return $this->fileType;
    }

    public function getFileSize() {
        $this->size = filesize($this->getFilePath());
        return $this->size;
    }

    // Transform the filesize in kilobytes, megabytes, ... and append the unit.
    public function getReadableSize() {
        $bytes = $this->getFileSize();
        $decimals = 2;
        $sz = 'BKMGTP';
        $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
        return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor];
    }

    // Get the HTML for the file list
    public function getTableRow() {

        F3::set('file', $this);
        // We check if the file exist before displaying the table row
        if (file_exists($this->getFilePath())) {
            $tableRow = F3::render('views/table_row.php');
            return $tableRow;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    // Get a file path on the server harddrive
    public function getFilePath() {
        $path = F3::get('rootPath');
        $uploadsFolder = F3::get('uploadFolder');
        $this->filePath = $path . '/' . $uploadsFolder . '/' . $this->systemFilename;
        return $this->filePath;
    }

    public function getSystemUrl() {
        $base = F3::get('BASE');
        $this->systemUrl = $base . '/file/' . $this->systemFilename;
        return $this->systemUrl;
    }

    public function getOriginalUrl() {
        $siteUrl = F3::get('siteUrl');
        $uploadsFolder = F3::get('uploadFolder');

        $this->originalUrl = $siteUrl . '/' . $uploadsFolder . '/' . $this->systemFilename;
        return $this->originalUrl;
    }

    public function getMime() {
        $filePath = $this->getFilePath();
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $info = $finfo->file($filePath);
        return $info;
    }

    public function gearUp($queryResult) {
        $this->id = $queryResult['id'];
        $this->fileName = $queryResult['fileName'];
        $this->systemFilename = $queryResult['systemFilename'];
        $this->fileType = $queryResult['fileType'];
        $this->ts = $queryResult['time'];
        $this->getSystemUrl();
        $this->getOriginalUrl();
        return $this;
    }

    // Display a single file
    public static function display($systemFilename) {
        $fileQuery = DB::sql('SELECT * FROM hm_files WHERE systemFilename LIKE "' . $systemFilename . '"');
        if (count($fileQuery) > 0) {
            $file = new file();
            $file->gearUp($fileQuery[0]);
            $mime = $file->getMime();
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file->fileName . '"');
            header('Content-type: ' . $mime);
            readfile($file->getOriginalUrl());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Build a zip of files
    // You can create direct download by setting $directDownload on true.
    // Important : we don't use the classic ZipArchive class of PHP. When we zip large files it produces errors.
    // We use the pclzip class. Doc: http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/
    public static function serveZip($idsArray, $token, $directDownload = true) {
        if (count($idsArray) > 0) {
            $rootPath = F3::get('rootPath');
            $zipPath = $rootPath . '/zips/archive-' . $token . '.zip';
            $zipper = new pclzip($zipPath);

            foreach ($idsArray as $id) {
                $file = file::fetch($id);
                $filePath = $file->getFilePath();
                $filesArray = array(
                    array(PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME => $filePath,
                        PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NEW_FULL_NAME => $file->fileName)
                );
                $zipper->add($filesArray, PCLZIP_OPT_NO_COMPRESSION, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
            }


            // We set the cookie to track the end of zipping
            setcookie('multiUp', $token);

            // If this is a direct download we serve the zip in the browser and then destroy the zipfile on the server
            if ($directDownload) {
                $zipContent = file_get_contents($zipPath);
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archive.zip"');
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                echo $zipContent;
                unlink($zipPath);
            }
        }
    }

    // Get info for a single file
    public static function fetch($id) {
        $fileQuery = DB::sql('SELECT * FROM hm_files WHERE id = ' . $id);
        if (count($fileQuery) > 0) {
            $file = new file();
            $file->gearUp($fileQuery[0]);

            return $file;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Fetch all files in the database
    public static function fetchAll() {
        $files = array();
        $filesId = DB::sql('SELECT id FROM hm_files ORDER BY time DESC');
        foreach ($filesId as $fileId) {
            $file = file::fetch($fileId['id']);
            if ($file) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }

    // Creates families for file extensions
    // Not used in this version. Might be usefull to create icons
    private function setKnownExtensions() {
        $fileTypes = array();

        // DOCUMENTS
        $fileTypes['pdf'] = 'pdf';

        // PLAIN TEXT
        $fileTypes['txt'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['rtf'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['as'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['xml'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['html'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['htm'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['js'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['php'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['asp'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['py'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['sql'] = 'text';
        $fileTypes['css'] = 'text';

        // ARCHIVES
        $fileTypes['zip'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['rar'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['7zip'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['gzip'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['gz'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['tgz'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['ace'] = 'archive';
        $fileTypes['arc'] = 'archive';

        // EXCEL
        $fileTypes['xls'] = 'excel';
        $fileTypes['xlsx'] = 'excel';
        $fileTypes['xlsm'] = 'excel';
        $fileTypes['ods'] = 'excel';
        $fileTypes['ots'] = 'excel';
        $fileTypes['csv'] = 'excel';
        $fileTypes['numbers'] = 'excel';

        // WORD
        $fileTypes['doc'] = 'word';
        $fileTypes['docx'] = 'word';
        $fileTypes['odt'] = 'word';
        $fileTypes['ott'] = 'word';
        $fileTypes['pages'] = 'word';

        // POWERPOINT
        $fileTypes['ppt'] = 'powerpoint';
        $fileTypes['pptx'] = 'powerpoint';
        $fileTypes['odp'] = 'powerpoint';
        $fileTypes['otp'] = 'powerpoint';
        $fileTypes['key'] = 'powerpoint';

        // IMAGES
        $fileTypes['png'] = 'image';

        $fileTypes['gif'] = 'image';
        $fileTypes['jpg'] = 'image';
        $fileTypes['jpeg'] = 'image';


        // UNCOMMON IMAGEs
        $fileTypes['svg'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['svgz'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['jpf'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['bmp'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['eps'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['tif'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['tiff'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['raw'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['pbm'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['tga'] = 'rareimage';
        $fileTypes['cdr'] = 'rareimage';



        // "WORKING" IMAGES
        $fileTypes['psd'] = 'photoshop';
        $fileTypes['psb'] = 'photoshop';

        $fileTypes['ai'] = 'illustrator';
        $fileTypes['ait'] = 'illustrator';
        $fileTypes['fxg'] = 'illustrator';
        $fileTypes['cgm'] = 'illustrator';

        $fileTypes['indd'] = 'indesign';
        $fileTypes['idml'] = 'indesign';

        $fileTypes['fla'] = 'flash';
        $fileTypes['swf'] = 'flash';
        $fileTypes['xfl'] = 'flash';

        $fileTypes['prproj'] = 'premiere';

        $fileTypes['aep'] = 'aftereffect';

        // 3D
        $fileTypes['3ds'] = '3d';
        $fileTypes['dwg'] = '3d';
        $fileTypes['dxf'] = '3d';
        $fileTypes['max'] = '3d';

        // SOUND / MUSIC
        $fileTypes['mp3'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['wav'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['flac'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['aac'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['aiff'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['aif'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['aifc'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['wma'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['au'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['snd'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['aa3'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['oma'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['at3'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['m3u'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['amr'] = 'music';
        $fileTypes['cda'] = 'music';

        //VIDEO
        $fileTypes['avi'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['flv'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['m4v'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['mkv'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['mov'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['mpeg'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['mpg'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['mpe'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['mp4'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['3gp'] = 'video';
        $fileTypes['aep'] = 'video';

        $this->knownExtensions = $fileTypes;
    }

}

?>
```

It worked fine on managed servers that have CPanel thats why i suspect my PHP.ini file? (i installed the server myself)

If it is the .ini file, what should i look for?

Comment: There is no code in anything you posted above that relates to uploading. Without the relevant code there is no way we can help you.

Comment: what do you want them to be named?

Comment: The original names...the problem is that the files i upload do not get their original names back..1.png for example converts to this long temp name, and stays this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script changes the file names on purpose, to guarantee they are always unique. This prevents a file from getting overwritten if someone uploads a file with the same file name. If you really want to retain the original name, you can change this line:

```
  $targetFile = str_replace('//', '/', $uploadUrl) . $this->systemFilename;
```

to this:

```
$targetFile = str_replace('//', '/', $uploadUrl) . $this->fileName;
```

Note that although the script assigns a unique name to each uploaded file, it still retains the original name in the database table as shown here:

```
 DB::sql('INSERT INTO hm_files (fileName, systemFilename, fileType, time) VALUES ("' . $this->fileName . '", "' . $this->systemFilename . '", "' . $this->fileType . '", ' . $this->ts . ')');
```